# Scheduling U - SQL Job

Tags: azure, apache-spark, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-lake

I am trying to schedule a U SQL job. Please let me know whether I can schedule the U SQL job.If so,how can I schedule.

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, the best way to orchestrate your U-SQL job along with concomitant data management such as getting source data, pushing output data and etc is [Azure Data Factory V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/). ADF has reach API. Basically, you can run your jobs using either PowerShell or C# or a trigger.

See my very simple example of the job and how to add a trigger below. In this example, I process the documents with my U-SQL job and then push output file (CSV  or Avro file) into  Azure SQL Server

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/) (with the help of the [Azure Data Lake Analytics Cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607124.aspx)) or [Azure Data Factory to schedule a U-SQL script](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-usql-activity/) in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some guidance regarding creating a ADF Pipeline here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-editor/

Comment: Link only answers should be comments